# php explicit iterate array without for or foreach

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I'm trying to iterate an array with next() current() and rewind():
is there a simple way to know when current pointer is arrived at the end ?

I just seen that when i'm at the end next() and current() returns both FALSE, but this also append when the array cells contain the FALSE boolean value.

edit:
of course sorry to not have specified that it's a numerical array.
I use it to and i'm trying to do a wordpress like

```
while ( have_post() )
      do_post()
```

but the origin can be both an array or a PDOStatement, like the follow:

```
class Document implements ContentGetter{
   private $array_or_rs;
   private $currentval;

   public function have_content() { //part of interface
      if( is_a($this->$array_or_rs, 'PDOStatement') ) {
          $result = PDOStatement-fetch();
          _do_things_
      } else {
          $result = next($this->$array_or_rs);
      }
      $this->$currentval = $result;
      return $result === FALSE;
   }

   public function get_content() { //part of interface
      return $this->$currentval;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why? Why are you reinventing the wheel? Homework maybe? :-)

Comment: Read on: [Iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)

Comment: imo the edit is too radical. I suggest to ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can I iterate over an array without using a foreach loop in PHP?**

Here you go:

```
$array = array(NULL, FALSE, 0);
while(list($key, $value) = each($array)) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

Output:

```
NULL
bool(false)
int(0)
```

`next()` and `current()` can't be used because there is no way to determine if a `FALSE` return value means a `FALSE` element or the end of the array. (As you've observed). However, you can use the function `each()`, as it will return an array containing the current key and value or `FALSE` at the end of the array. After it has been executed, the current-pointer will be set to the next element.

I must admit that I've not used that since > 10 years. :) However it is a basic PHP function and it still works.

**How to implement the WordPres-like `ContentGetter` interface?**

I would make usage of PHP's `Iterator` concept. You can wrap either the array in to an `ArrayIterator` or the `PDOStatement` into a `PDOStatementIterator`. While this first is a built-in class of PHP, the latter has to be written. Alternatively you can use [this one](http://code.google.com/p/php-axiom/source/browse/trunk/libraries/PDOStatementIterator.class.php?spec=svn46&r=46) (looks good, but contains more functionality than required for this task)

Based on that, the `Document` class should look like this:

```
class Document implements ContentGetter {

    /**
     * @var Iterator
     */
    protected $iterator;

    /**
     * @param array|PDOStatement $stmtOrArray
     */
    public function __construct($stmtOrArray) {
        if(is_a($stmtOrArray, 'PDOStatement')) {
            $this->iterator = new PDOStatementIterator($stmtOrArray);
        } else if(is_array($stmtOrArray)) {
            $this->iterator = new ArrayIterator($stmtOrArray);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Expected array or PDOStatement');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for Iterator::valid()
     */
    public function have_content() {
        return $this->iterator->valid();
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for Iterator::current() + Iterator::next()
     */
    public function get_content() {
        $item = $this->iterator->current();
        $this->iterator->next();
        return $item;
    }
}
```

**Tests:**

```
// Feed Document with a PDOStatement
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', 'user', 'password');
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2'); // stupid query ...

$doc = new Document($result);
while($doc->have_content()) {
    var_dump($doc->get_content());
}
```

.

```
// Feed Document with an array
$doc = new Document(array(1, 2, 3));
while($doc->have_content()) {
    var_dump($doc->get_content());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could compare key() to sizeof($my_array)

Comment: This is only true for numeric arrays.